# How do I update a specific array of objects in a document's array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mui-x-data-grid

The document is as follows:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "64f832a51e7647d451ea8daa"
  },
  "requisitionOpenDate": "6/9/2023/ 13:34:37",
  "requisitionId": 33280,
  "requestorName": "Amar",
  "requestorEmail": "amaresh@pwc.com",
  "projectSbu": "1",
  "projectStage": "2",
  "projectCompetency": "1",
  "projectCodeCreated": "1",
  "projectCode": 12345,
  "salesforceId": 12345,
  "resourceDetails": [
     {
       "rowid": "025820850bb6-7408257gh9",
       "level": "Beginner",
       "experience": 6,
       "location": "Maine",
       "_id": "...."
     },
     {
       "rowid": "72504385254mm7-74238474hj4",
       "level": "Advanced",
       "experience": 7,
       "location": "Vienna",
       "_id": "...."
     }
  ],
  "__v": 0
}
```

I want to update the rowid:  "025820850bb6-7408257gh9", to have the following details:

```
     {
       "rowid": "025820850bb6-7408257gh9",
       "level": "Rookie",
       "experience": 6.3,
       "location": "Vancouver",
       "_id": "...."
     }
```

And if the rowid doesn't exist, I want to add it as a new object. I'm trying to write this logic in my Nodejs api, and can't figure this out. Would appreciate the help.

Note: The rowid is something that I'm receiving from MUI/x-data-grid, it isn't the same as "_id" given by MongoDB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something as follow :

1. Match the document you want to update
2. Check if rowid exists. If so, merge the corresponding nested object with your wanted object. Else, add your object at the end.

```
db.collection.update({
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "64f832a51e7647d451ea8daa"
  }
},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "resourceDetails": {
        "$cond": {
          if: {
            $in: [
              "025820850bb6-7408257gh9",
              {
                "$ifNull": [
                  "$resourceDetails.rowid",
                  []
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          then: {
            $map: {
              input: "$resourceDetails",
              in: {
                $cond: {
                  if: {
                    $eq: [
                      "$$this.rowid",
                      "025820850bb6-7408257gh9"
                    ]
                  },
                  then: {
                    $mergeObjects: [
                      "$$this",
                      {
                        "rowid": "025820850bb6-7408257gh9",
                        "level": "Rookie",
                        "experience": 6.3,
                        "location": "Vancouver",
                        "_id": "...."
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  else: "$$this"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          else: {
            "$concatArrays": [
              {
                $ifNull: [
                  "$resourceDetails",
                  []
                ]
              },
              [
                {
                  "rowid": "025820850bb6-7408257gh9",
                  "level": "Rookie",
                  "experience": 6.3,
                  "location": "Vancouver",
                  "_id": "...."
                }
              ]
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

You can test it here [MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/25ieGQaff9V)